# Passing a variable to a jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works:

```
function rowColors(){
     $("table#remotes th").css("background-color", "#202020");
     $("table#remotes tr").css("background-color", "#484848");
     $("table#remotes tr:visible:odd").css("background-color", "#333333");
 }
```

How can I make this work with a variable table id? This doesn't work:

```
function rowColors(tblid){
    $("table#"+tblid+" th").css("background-color", "#202020");
    $("table#"+tblid+" tr").css("background-color", "#484848");
    $("table#"+tblid+" tr:visible:odd").css("background-color", "#333333");
}
```

rowColors(remotes);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe because `remotes` is a variable and not a string

```
rowColors('remotes');
```

Comment: Yeah, it's worth mentioning this has nothing to do with jQuery specifically.